# Using C# HttpWebRequest with not typical URL

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am using the following function to receive an Artifacory repo mapping:

```
private string LoadHttpPageWithBasicAuthentication(string url, string username, string password)
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
    WebRequest myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);

    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;

    NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

    CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    myCredentialCache.Add(myUri, "Basic", myNetworkCredential);

    myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentialCache;

    WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

    string pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    responseStream.Close();

    myWebResponse.Close();

    return pageContent;
}
```

The URL that i am trying to pass looks like that -

> http://ArtifactoryRepo?list&deep=1&listFolders=1&mdTimestamps=1

But from the result it seems that the request ignores part of the URL.
The results that received are only for that part of the URL -

> http://ArtifactoryRepo

I tried to split URL for two separate parameters but it doesn't worked

Any ideas ?

Thnaks

Comment: does the `myUri` variable retain the query string part, or is it gone missing after `new Uri(...)` already?

Comment: Your `list` query variable does not contain any value, did you mean to do something like `?list=1`? Also, make sure to escape your values if needed...

Comment: Originally i am passing url="ArtifactoryRepo?list&deep=1&listFolders=1&mdTimesta…; But i am getting the same result as i will pass url="ArtifactoryRepo"

the `list` is a part of api syntax...
[Jenkind API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API)

It not gone missing after new Uri(...)

Comment: You are missing the top-level domain in this link

Comment: And what the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there was a problem with credentials, so i used Convert.Tobase64string() function.
And webReq.Method was not defined.
Finally found [that](http://forum.aws.chdev.org/t/c-example-to-authorise-and-get-data-from-api/388) function to do the job.